# I cant log into phpmyadmin and get an error

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

I am a bloody beginner when it comes to website building. After I put wordpress per FTP on my hosted domain I need the MySQL Password. Because the databank is build automaticly I need to open the .my.cnf file in phpmyadmin. Now when I try to log into  the web interface I get this error:

mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'eisenast.uber.space'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

My googlesearch didnt find anything with the same problem. I tried all the passwords and usernames in different combinations that I had.

Comment: Did you verify your credentials? Are you sure you are entering the right username and password?

Comment: I tried every username and password that I have for this site. I thought that I maybe is another error

Comment: The message is pretty clear. The username-password combination is incorrect. Ask your admin what is the correct password or if you are the admin then reset the password in MySQL.